# Soap-server responds with error 12030 after requests over HTTPS

Tags: delphi, soap, https, winhttp

My Delphi 10.4 application uses a HTTPRIO-component to communicates with SOAP REST Server over HTTPS.
It is installed on more then 100 PC's, and it works fine almost everywhere.
However, I now have 2 clients that get the following error:

*"Error sending data: (12030). De verbinding met de server is niet normaal beëindigd"*
(--> The connection to the server did not end normally )

The user has a Windows 7 Home Premium machine (I have Windows 10 Pro).
Firewall was disabled.

**If I copy the complete application-dirctory with all the dll's to my machine everything works fine.**

Where should I start looking for a solution?
Which properties of the HTTPRIO-component could have an effect on this behaviour? Or which dll's?

I checked the article Peter Wolf suggested but without succes. (The register-settings should be OK). All the registers are present with the right values, but the windows update could not be installed. Also downloading the stand-alone update KB3140245 fails. It juist says "failed".

any hints are welcome!

kind regards,

Dirk Janssens

Comment: I guess this is because the Win7 machine does not support security protocol required by the endpoint or it is not enabled. See [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392)

Comment: Regarding your edit: the registry keys are present, **and** the update from the linked article has been **installed**? (check the file date / version information)